# Is it time to start ranking questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, new-users

Yes, I know this question has been touched on before, but mostly in comments and never really resolved.

As I understand it, the main, original and intended purpose of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of high quality questions and answers. Votes, edits and comments are all aimed at meeting that goal. And it works. For many categories of question Google will find Stack Overflow before other more specialised sites, mainly because the answers are better.

This purpose is being significantly diluted by the flood of newbies using Stack Overflow as a homework problem solver. The questions are easy to recognise, we all know them well, and they tend to get answers because they are easy targets for people trying to build reputation. However, while they serve the questioner and perhaps the answerer, they do not serve the overall purpose of the site. They (usually) do not add to the repository of knowledge (unless someone else happens to have the same homework question).

The high levels of low-grade question flow make it harder for others to find and answer more interesting questions. You can always hang out on a tag like "language-lawyer" and be pretty safe, but if you really are interested in the finer points of C/C++/Java/.NET programming you are likely to be overrun.

These questions do not get closed. There are enough people who like to answer them that they tend to survive even when they shouldn't.

I thought about pushing these questions onto a new 'newbie' site. However, the only reason people answer them is to build reputation on Stack Overflow and that would defeat the purpose.

In my opinion a basic question ranking system could be the answer. The proposed rules are:

1. Three levels: newbie, regular, advanced.
2. Level assigned automatically based on rep: newbie if < 100, otherwise regular.
3. Newbie questioner can claim regular level, subject to review.
4. Rep > 500 can claim advanced level, subject to challenge and review.

The level could be implemented as a tag, so existing searching mechanisms would work. People who want to build rep on easy questions know where to find them. People who want to contribute real knowledge can simply suppress the newbie tag.

That's probably too complicated, but it tries to bring out the essentials of a solution to a real problem. If it really is a bad idea, then just put it to rest and can can all forget about it.

---

Please note: this is absolutely not about ranking users. We already do that -- any rank above 1K has a goodly amount of work and skill behind it and we all know that, even if we all sometimes ask really dumb questions.

This is about ranking questions. High rep users are free to ask newbie questions if they wish (although it's primarily intended for very low rep users), so that those who want to answer newbie questions can find them, and those who don't can look elsewhere. The advanced level was intended to allow flagging challenging questions for which a quick one liner will not be enough. Maybe leave that for another time.

I envisage a low rep user (<100 but maybe even <20) to automatically have their question set at level newbie, but offered something like:

> As a new user your questions are automatically set to level newbie. If you are a skilled programmer or you believe your question is at a harder level, you may request that it be graded at level regular. It will then be reviewed for suitability.

Comment: isnt downvoting a form of ranking?

Comment: Question difficulty is not proportional to the reputation of a user.

Comment: Hi, user1234567. You are level `newbie`. Enjoy your stay at SE!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/how-about-a-difficulty-rating-for-questions

Comment: @gnat: How do you find them? I had a good look first but it didn't come up in my searches. Anyway, that's a five year old question so maybe it deserves another look.

Comment: BTW I still don't understand the enthusiasm with which questions get down-voted on MSO. I'd ask a question about it, but...

Comment: @david.pfx You have a "feature-request" and a lot of the votes are people stating either they do or don't want your proposed feature implementing.

Answer (score 5):

I really don't like the idea of user ranks. It seems tacky and reminiscent of fora, which is one of the things Stack Overflow was intended to replace.

The main problem I've got with it, though, is that new users can post great questions and answers and users who have been here for some time can still post bad questions. A central tenet of Stack Overflow has seemed to be that we should focus on the content, not the user (hence serial downvoting being disallowed and so on). Introducing user ranks that would affect organization of questions starts making the user a part of the considerations when evaluating a question.

As is, a user, new or experienced, can post a question. If it is a good question, it may be upvoted. If it is a bad question, it may be downvoted or, if necessary, closed. If we put questions from new users in their own area, we may have an increase in quality in the experienced-user bin and a decrease in quality in the new-user bin. That encourages experienced users to stop looking in the new-user question bin, and so the real gems that *do* show up in the new-user bin may not get the upvotes they deserve. Besides, if all the new users who could potentially write good content see a bunch of awful content in the new-user area, we could have an outbreak of the [broken window effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory). That's no good.

Said another way, the current method lacking user ranks makes it relatively easy for new users who *have* read the community guidelines and can write good questions to gain reputation and earn privileges. Putting in a system of user ranks puts in a potentially difficult-to-surpass wall, making it harder for new users, even those who contribute good content (those we absolutely want to draw and keep), to rise in rank.

Comment: Privileges already sort of establish a ranking system if you think about it... even the 20k privilege is called "trusted user". But you're right, not the same kind of ranking system as what the question is proposing.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes. I suppose what makes this proposal different is that you'd be able to filter questions by the rank of the asker, and I think that could be rather harmful. Privileges do establish a sort of separation, but it's not something that isolates people of different privilege levels.

Comment: So, will you add a comment about question difficulty independent of user rank? You are certainly right about not conflating them.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Then that sounds similar to [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/how-about-a-difficulty-rating-for-questions), which was [meta-tag:status-declined].

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe this would work at all, and here's why:

Not every programmer in the world has an account on SO. Even if they did, reputation points are a measure of involvement, and to some extent popularity, not of experience, knowledge, intelligence, or the ability to ask and/or answer increasingly difficult questions. Granted, popularity often stems from those things. Reputation points themselves, however do not come directly from them, but from how they manifest in community interaction.

The point is, a brand-new user might be a programming expert who just had not bothered to make an account previously. If his question was ranked "newbie", it would never get answered, because only other (ie. actual) newbs would see it, and none of them would be able to answer it.

Conceptually, the ranked-question idea has some merit, in my opinion. But the only way to implement it would be to:

1. Have users assign a difficulty to their own questions, or
2. Have some moderators scrawl the site 24/7 and assign difficulties to questions.

Option 1 is not good because users could easily misuse it by giving their questions harder difficulties so that higher-ranked people would see it. They also might not know how difficult their question is relative to community standards, and might inadvertently assign the wrong difficulty.

Option 2 is just not feasible, because who would want to waste their life doing that?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I covered option 1. A skilled newbie would be allowed to claim a higher level, and it would then have to be approved by review. That would be a far smaller number than option 2.

Comment: The process of reviewing could end up being like a combination of Option 1 and 2. We would need people to review the supposed "higher ranked" people, which would take time. There are a lot of new users on SO, it wouldn't be a 10-minute-per-day job, and they would still need to be on-duty 24/7 regardless. Also, reviewers could easily be biased. I don't believe there is any current standard for question difficulty to reference, and it would be no simple task to make one.